# Is there a directory in android FS accessible/readable by any app?

Tags: android, permissions, filesystems

I am making a small database of ttyUSB devices plugged in on an android device. To that extent, I made android *`ueventd`* write into a file to save some information like: vid, pid, serial and device path (e.g. `/dev/ttyUSB0`). I would like this file to be accessible by any android apps.

1. Is there a directory in android FS accessible/readable by any app? Preferrably one that does not need special permissions. In which I could put my file?
2. Is there a security risk in making a usb device's serial number accessible this way to android apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like this file to be accessible by any android apps.

Why? Do you think the user wants this data "to be accessible by any android apps"? What does the user gain by your disclosing this data?

> Is there a directory in android FS accessible/readable by any app? Preferrably one that does not need special permissions. In which I could put my file?

External storage is accessible by all apps, but it will require a permission to read from in future versions of Android. There is no other place accessible by all apps.

> Is there a security risk in making a usb device's serial number accessible this way to android apps?

Possibly. There may be a privacy risk.

Please keep the file protected, and create a `ContentProvider` that you secure via a permission. That way, when users install apps that wish to access your data, the *user* gets to decide if that can happen or not.

Also, bear in mind that the *ueventd* stuff that you are doing is beyond the scope of the Android SDK. If you are doing this in some ROM mod that you are creating, fine. If you are trying to play games with *ueventd* on arbitrary hardware, bear in mind that *ueventd* behavior may vary by device.

Comment: At least, I need the file to be accessible by one app, which might not be installed in the first place. So the external location (in my case `/sdcard`) is the only place I could put my stuff in, if I mock which app is going to make use of this information. I build android from sources and generate custom ROM for pandaboard, I am aware my changes only apply to such hardware, it's ok. "create a ContentProvider that you secure via a permission" how could I possibly do that, considering I mainly modify `system/core/init` stuff?

Comment: @m-ric: "how could I possibly do that" -- I have no idea, sorry. I thought that you were perhaps working at the SDK level with a rooted device or something.

Comment: My question was not specific enough on this regard, thanks for your help.